# Is there any way to mark\flag a table in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, flags

I am looking for a smart, simple way for my app to remember if my table is checked or not.

The logical way would be to create a table with the names of all tables and a boolean value for each one. Another way would be to do that with `SharedPreferences`.

Are there any other options that not involving the db, perhaps like a tag or something like that?

In the end, all I want is for the app to remember if a table set share or not.

Comment: Do you want to remember it across restarts or just while in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables) explains how to create your own subclass of android.app.Application which you can store global variables in. This same approach should help you achieve what you want to do without using a database or shared preferences.